# How to draw a MKPolyline on a MKMapSnapshot

Tags: ios, ios7, mapkit

In iOS 7 you can make static snapshots of a map using the MapKit framework. Very useful if you want to send someone an email with a location or something. The only thing that I am missing is: How can I draw an MKPolyline on that snapshot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how:

```
- (UIImage *)drawRoute:(MKPolyline *)polyline onSnapshot:(MKMapSnapshot *)snapShot withColor:(UIColor *)lineColor {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(snapShot.image.size);
CGRect rectForImage = CGRectMake(0, 0, snapShot.image.size.width, snapShot.image.size.height);

// Draw map
[snapShot.image drawInRect:rectForImage];

// Get points in the snapshot from the snapshot
int lastPointIndex;
int firstPointIndex = 0;
BOOL isfirstPoint = NO;
NSMutableArray *pointsToDraw = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < polyline.pointCount; i++){
    MKMapPoint point = polyline.points[i];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D pointCoord = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(point);
    CGPoint pointInSnapshot = [snapShot pointForCoordinate:pointCoord];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(rectForImage, pointInSnapshot)) {
        [pointsToDraw addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pointInSnapshot]];
        lastPointIndex = i;
        if (i == 0)
            firstPointIndex = YES;
        if (!isfirstPoint) {
            isfirstPoint = YES;
            firstPointIndex = i;
        }
    }
}

// Adding the first point on the outside too so we have a nice path
    if (lastPointIndex+1 <= polyline.pointCount {
    MKMapPoint point = polyline.points[lastPointIndex+1];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D pointCoord = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(point);
    CGPoint pointInSnapshot = [snapShot pointForCoordinate:pointCoord];
    [pointsToDraw addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pointInSnapshot]];
}
// Adding the point before the first point in the map as well (if needed) to have nice path

if (firstPointIndex != 0) {
    MKMapPoint point = polyline.points[firstPointIndex-1];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D pointCoord = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(point);
    CGPoint pointInSnapshot = [snapShot pointForCoordinate:pointCoord];
    [pointsToDraw insertObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pointInSnapshot] atIndex:0];
}

// Draw that points
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);

for (NSValue *point in pointsToDraw){
    CGPoint pointToDraw = [point CGPointValue];
    if ([pointsToDraw indexOfObject:point] == 0){
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, pointToDraw.x, pointToDraw.y);
    } else {
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pointToDraw.x, pointToDraw.y);
    }
}
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [lineColor CGColor]);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return resultingImage;
}
```

I know this is maybe not the best way to do, so if you have a nicer or faster way to do: Please share :)

Comment: I use a similar approach to create images of routes saved to core data :  create snapshop, graphics context based on the snapshot, generate a CLLocationCoordinate2D from lat and long for each core data point, use pointForCoordinate to check if point in snapshot and then draw.  Works well but I’m still testing on more complex routes - I’ll post if I find anything that adds to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I converted plaetzchen's answer to a swift 4 extension for MKMapSnapshot

```
import MapKit

extension MKMapSnapshot {

    func drawPolyline(_ polyline: MKPolyline, color: UIColor, lineWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.image.size)
        let rectForImage = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.image.size.width, height: self.image.size.height)

        // Draw map
        self.image.draw(in: rectForImage)

        var pointsToDraw = [CGPoint]()


        let points = polyline.points()
        var i = 0
        while (i < polyline.pointCount)  {
            let point = points[i]
            let pointCoord = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(point)
            let pointInSnapshot = self.point(for: pointCoord)
            pointsToDraw.append(pointInSnapshot)
            i += 1
        }

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context!.setLineWidth(lineWidth)

        for point in pointsToDraw {
            if (point == pointsToDraw.first) {
                context!.move(to: point)
            } else {
                context!.addLine(to: point)
            }
        }

        context?.setStrokeColor(color.cgColor)
        context?.strokePath()

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}
```

You invoke it like this:

```
let image = mapSnapshot.drawPolyline(polyline, color: uiColor, lineWidth: 4)
```